# Yocto Linux Smart IP Routing between Wifi and Ethernet

Tags: routes, mono, wifi, ethernet, yocto

I'm currently running with a custom built machine in my car that I'm trying to get to intelligently connect to the internet.

It has a WiFi and an Ethernet connection, but both are intermittent. WiFi is available when near my set up access point, but the Ethernet is plugged into a cell modem, which sometimes loses connection in dead zones.

When I try to access the internet through my software, it always picks eth0, even if eth0 has no internet but wlan0 does. Is there a way for Yocto/Linux to detect which interface can connect to the internet and use that one? Basically, I'd like it to automatically select the other interface for internet is the one it tries first fails to provide a connection.

At the moment, my current solution is to have my software periodically edit the default route in the route table, attempt to Ping, and if successful, use that route. But I am looking for an OS based solution, or any other simpler solution.

Thank you for your time, I will edit the question as requested with clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate` could help you?

You can check for any interface you have.

Comment: Sadly, this only tells me if the interface is up, and not whether or not it can get out to the internet. Ran a test where I disconnected the sim card in the attached cell modem. operstate was up but I couldn't ping out.

Comment: What about `ip link list` (for default gate), or `netstat -rn`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what to be looking for in ip link list, but netstat just gives me the result of route, which is the same regardless of connection status.